# How can I view the manual page for "set" from within bash

Tags: bash, manual

I do

> man set

but that just gets me this:

[image]

How can I get to here: http://ss64.com/bash/set.html from within bash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bash` built-ins don't have their own man pages; you need to use `bash`'s built-in help system:

```
$ help set
```

Comment: Does this command print the same as it's written at http://ss64.com/bash/set.html? It does not for me on 4.3.30. I looked for in `Bash git` repository and didn't find this sentence: "Manipulate shell variables and functions.". I wonder where do they get it from at http://ss64.com?

Comment: I think that's just a custom web page, not included in `bash` itself.

Comment: that must be the case

Comment: Note that a lot of commands they have under the "bash" index are external commands that are completely independent of `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `man bash`, scroll down to the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section, then scroll down to the `set` command.

Comment: Except that there are about 17 hits for the string "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" before the one you want (which is thousands of lines down). BUT if you search for it with "^" in front  (to find it only at start of line), you can get there quickly (at least on Ubuntu and Mac OS X).